# How can I define the size of an image using either css or bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently in the process of building a website and I am running into some trouble. [home_page_ideal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLSR2.jpg) is what the page is supposed to look like ideally. My issue is with the little boxed image on the top left. When I scroll all the way up, the page looks like [home_page_issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7I1E.png). The CSS related code is:

```
.logo {
  padding: 38px 0;
}

img {
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

The bootstrap classes col-md-2, col-sm-6, col-xs-12 are also used for one the parent div. Not sure if it's relevant, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to mention it.

I would like the image to stay boxed on the top left of the page when one scrolls all the way up. I had a dummy image on there before and everything worked fine, but then I replaced it with the actual image needing to be there and this happened.

Could it possibly have something to do with the size of the image? I'm not sure but any help, hints, or lead would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a max-width or max-height so that way it won't get larger than a certain size. The auto makes it take up the width of the parent, and if the parent is col-xs-12, it'll be full screen.

Comment: Didn't work. Those classes are for the drop-down menu. I just wanted the logo to be on the far left of the page.

Comment: @MaximillianNaza- This answer absolutely would work.  A response of "Didn't work" is pretty useless.  What didn't work about it?  What style did you use? Are you sure your style addressed the proper element?

Comment: Sorry about that. When I applied his fix my drop-down menu disappeared, and my issue still remained. Sorry again for not saying enough.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out what was wrong. It had to do with the size of the image so once I resized my logo everything was back to normal. The dummy img I originally had was 134 x 32, and my logo when I did the replacement was 1400 x 1235. In other words, my logo was just too big.

Comment: Given the information in the question, there was no way for anyone else to answer this. It would be best to simply delete this question, as it is unlikely to help anyone else with a similar problem.